# Issue parsing JSON object response to C# object

Tags: c#, json, rest, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have the following code:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool AddUser(long warnId, double longitude, double latitude)
{
    try
    {
        string jsonFeature = string.Empty;
        jsonFeature += "[{'geometry': {'x': " + longitude + ",'y': " + latitude +
                       ",'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}},'attributes': {'UID': '";
        jsonFeature += warnId + "','Latitude': '" + latitude + "','Longitude': '" + longitude + "'}}]";

        string reqURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WARNURL"] + "addFeatures";

        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            var collection = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            collection.Add("f", "json");
            collection.Add("features", jsonFeature);
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues(reqURL, "POST", collection);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(response);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string aRespStr = reader.ReadToEnd();

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            AddResult addResult = jss.Deserialize<AddResult>(aRespStr);


            return aRespStr.Contains("true") && aRespStr.Contains("success");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        string message = e.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

when I run it the string aRespStr is:

> "{\"addResults\":[{\"objectId\":28,\"globalId\":\"{740490C6-77EE-4AC0-9561-5EBAACE3A0A7}
>   \",\"success\":true}]}"

I created the following classes to hold the object once I deserialize it:

```
    public class Error
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class AddResult
{
    public int objectId { get; set; }
    public object globalId { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<AddResult> addResults { get; set; }
}
```

but when I run the code the addResult object contains the default object values not the json object values.

The api for this particular response is here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/fsadd.html

any help on getting this to work is greatly appreciated

Comment: The string matches your RootObject class but you are deserializing as AddResult in your code sample.

Comment: thanks bmavity, when I changed it to deserialize to the RootObject it worked great

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RootObject addResults=jss.Deserialize<RootObject>(aRespStr);
```

or similary you can try this

```
List<AddResult> addResults = jss.Deserialize<List<AddResult>>(aRespStr);
```

as you are returning list of AddResult in your json Response.

And Change the content type to application/json

Answer (score 0):

change

```
client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

to

```
client.Headers["Content-type"] = "Application/json";
```